# Making two programs talk with each other

Tags: c#, client-server, project

My group in the university are working on a project, which includes us making a C# program. We have a vision of making a server side console program that is constantly calculating data and then make a client side program that can fetch the data from our server side program. The client side program will then be able to display the data and the user is able to navigate forth and back around the data. Both of these programs will be run on the same computer solely for exercise purpose.

I am wondering how I can get data from the server side program and be able to display it on the client side program.

Comment: What exactly is your question here?

Comment: [You could use WCF](http://weblogs.asp.net/ralfw/a-truely-simple-example-to-get-started-with-wcf)

Comment: I am wondering how i can get data from the server side program and be able to display it on the client side program.

Comment: since you are learning do it with by wrting a simple TCP server and thats really easy to do using `System.Net.Sockets`, google tcp server client examples, forget all the WCF nonsense for now.

Comment: If both client and server will be on the same machine there is no need at all to use WCF or sockets... You can use [named pipes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546085(v=vs.110).aspx) which provide interprocess communication.

Answer (score 2):

If both client and server are always on the same machine, there is no need at all to use WCF or Sockets. You can use [named pipes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546085(v=vs.110).aspx) for the interprocess communication.

If you're trying to do a more serious client/server application, I recommend you to try [Redis](http://redis.io/) which provides a lot of remote features like pub/sub and caching, so you'll avoid reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments that sounds like you would like to create a "server" like application which you could do with WCF.
http://tech.pro/tutorial/855/wcf-tutorial-basic-interprocess-communication

There are also some workarounds if you wish to do so, using a Database or use a folder containing Text Files,that would include a folder watcher, which you than read, but they are not that elegant.

Comment: Thanks. I am reading about WCF right now and me and my group mate are thinking that would be the way to go for the implementation.

Comment: if you want to keep calculating data you will need 4 pieces with this method. You will need the a WCF service for the center of the project. a database to store calculation results, a server application constanly running and calculating and sending result to the WCF service, and a client app querying the WCF to return the calculation results.

Answer (score 0):

You can get data to the client program by configuring it by using web.api self hosting. Here is a great link. The server app can be configured to use the same thing. They can both listen and answer one another.

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/b1df45/Asp-Net-web-api-self-hosting/

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you give [ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api) a chance?
You'll be creating a REST API that not only a C# program can talk to (any language/implementation - even another server) can talk to your server as long as the end point is correct (in your case would be your IP address and port number) & of course, you don't need both programs to be on the same computer as well :)